# Cloud Firestore: listen for new documents in a collection and load them

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a messaging app using Firebase and Cloud Firestore. I have a collection called "messages" that contains documents for each message. My main goal is to listen to that collection for new documents and load them *without* reloading all the documents in the collection.

**EDIT:** In a nutshell, I want the client to load messages saved by other clients.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That depends on what defines when a document is "new" for you.

If "new" means "created after now()", then you need to have a `created` timestamp in your document and query to start at `now()`. That's pretty similar to what David explained here for the Firebase Realtime Database: [How to only get new data without existing data from a Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885059/how-to-only-get-new-data-without-existing-data-from-a-firebase)

If "new" means "documents this user hasn't loaded before", you will need to track the latest document they've seen, and start a query at that document. Kato explained a similar model for the Firebase Realtime here: [Firebase child_added without loading all data first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312783/firebase-child-added-without-loading-all-data-first)

Comment: This works great. The `created` timestamp is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Below a code in Java (for Android) that listen each new created document in the collection, which has a field named `ts_created` (a timestamp).

```java
    final Query queryLastDocument = db.collection("messages")
      .orderBy("ts_created", Direction.DESCENDING)
      .limit(1);
    
    queryLastDocument.addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
      if (error != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error. Newer documents listen failed.", error);
        return;
      }
    
      assert value != null;
      Log.d(TAG, "Newer document found!");
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
      }
    });
```